# How to create Typescript module definition a for a babel-plugin-content-transformer directory?

Tags: typescript, module, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm using [babel-plugin-content-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-content-transformer) to load a directory of YAML documents in React Native/Expo.

My babel plugin is configured as follows:

```
   ['content-transformer', {
        transformers: [{
          file: /\.ya?ml$/,
          format: 'string'
        }],
        content: [
          // Import statements ending with "content" are converted into
          // an array of imports. The array will ony include ".y(a)ml" files
          {
            dir: /texts$/,
            filter: /\.ya?ml$/
          }
        ]
      }]
```

This is working, and I can both load individual YAMLs as strings, and the whole `texts` directory as an object.

My question is **how do I declare a typed module for `texts`**?

Within my `types.d.ts` I have this:

```js
declare module '*.yaml' {
    const data: string
    export default data
}
```

Which works for loading in individual YAMLs. But when I try to import the whole directory (which I've verified works if I ignore the compiler) this doesn't work:

```js
declare module 'texts' {
    const data: Record<string, string>
    export default data
}
// results in Cannot find module '../../texts' or its corresponding type declarations.
// when I try to load from "../../texts"
```

Is this possible, and if so what's the right way to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: My usage is really simple: `import singleFile from "../../texts/myFile.yaml"` works (imports a string), but `import allFiles from "../../texts"` results in the error in my question ("Cannot find module). If I ignore the TS Error, `allFiles` correctly resolves to an object containing all the files.

Comment: Would you consider editing your question so that it focuses on the parts that are more likely generalizable/helpful to other people? As you have learned, the core part of this problem is solely about TypeScript behaviour, so it can even benefit people who don't use Webpack or Babel. You wouldn't necessarily need to remove the parts about Webpack or Babel (although I don't think that would be a bad thing)- you could just de-emphasize them as parts of your context that may not apply to other people encountering the same core problem. I would suggest an edit, but I'd rather talk about it first.

Comment: @rainbow.gekota I appreciate you commenting about it. The problem is that, without having this problem, I wouldn't have known what questions to ask. I had absolutely no idea that this was in any way related to TypeScript wildcards gobbing the beginning of a path. If someone knows the correct keywords to get here, then they still could find it via the answer being indexed. tl;dr; I think specific questions are more helpful than general questions, as people are usually dealing with specific (not general) problems.

Comment: This question would have helped me. I doubt I would have ever found this question if the focus was generalized-- I didn't know any of the key words or underlying concepts. Of course, if there's a good generalization that maintains specificity, I could be open to it. Feel free to make an edit-- I'm not promising I'll accept it, but I'll seriously consider it.

Comment: I don't know how much this applies today, but back in 2011, the stance was: ["It is OK to edit a question to make it more general. With the power of editing comes the power to take someone’s \[...\], very specific question, and edit it a little bit until they’re asking the more general question that hundreds of people encounter"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Reading the Docs

In the following snippet, `declare module '*.yaml' {...}` is an [ambient module declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) *named* `*.yaml`. The `*` part of the name `*.yaml` is a wildcard character. Wildcards in module names was a feature introduced in TypeScript v2.0:

> TypeScript 2.0 supports the use of the wildcard character (*) to declare a “family” of module names; this way, a declaration is only required once for an extension, and not for every resource.

[The docs on TypeScript's module resolution logic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) states:

> First, the compiler will try to locate a file that represents the imported module. To do so the compiler follows one of two different strategies: Classic or Node. These strategies tell the compiler where to look for moduleA.
>
> If that didn’t work and if the module name is non-relative (and in the case of "moduleA", it is), then the compiler will attempt to locate an ambient module declaration. We’ll cover non-relative imports next.

##### Applying the Docs to Context

Here's where things get surprising. In that "later", it states:

> A relative import is resolved relative to the importing file and **cannot resolve to an ambient module declaration**. You should use relative imports for your own modules that are guaranteed to maintain their relative location at runtime.

(emphasis added). If that's the case, then how did the compiler resolve your `import singleFile from "../../texts/myFile.yaml"`? The path there clearly contains a relative path, and resolves to an ambient module declaration.

##### Comparing the Docs with Actual Behaviour

The reason is because the wildcard functionality doesn't do anything special with path resolution. It doesn't care that `../` means "relative parent" in the filesystem world. It just sees that `../../texts/myFile` can be resolved with the wildcard, and that the remaining `.yaml` in the import matches the remaining `.yaml` in the ambient module declaration name.

Try doing:

- `import singleFile from "../../../../AAA/texts/myFile.yaml"`
- `import singleFile from "/texts/myFile.yaml"`
- `import singleFile from "C:\\//\\\\/myFile.yaml"`

They should resolve to the ambient module declaration just the same even though resolving that relative path would actually fail on the filesystem.

##### Denouemont

So why is your attempt to do `import allFiles from "../../texts"` failing? It's because there's no wildcard in the name of your ambient module declaration for the text folder, so the `../../` before `text` means it doesn't resolve to the ambient module that you have declared with the name `text`. If you name your ambient module declaration `*text`, it should then resolve how you want. Or, you can change your import to `import allFiles from "texts"`. Since you use a build-system (WebPack) which also has its own module resolution machinery, you might want to use the first approach, where the relative path can be interpreted and used by the build-system machinery in a way that prevents it from being as "leaky" (resolvable by other imports in unintended and surprising ways).

##### Closing Thoughts

What I find troubling is that the current documentation (2022/10/05) seems contradictory to actual behaviour:

> If that didn’t work and if the module name is **non**-relative [...], then the compiler will attempt to locate an ambient module declaration.
>
> [...]
>
> A relative import is resolved relative to the importing file and **cannot resolve to an ambient module declaration**. You should use relative imports for your own modules that are guaranteed to maintain their relative location at runtime.

I'm not sure if my experiential understanding of the TS compiler behaviour is 100% right, but perhaps the docs should be saying something like:

> If that didn’t work, then the compiler will attempt to locate an ambient module declaration.
>
> [...]
>
> A relative import is resolved relative to the importing file and if that resolution fails, an attempt at resolving to an ambient module declaration is made. You should use relative imports for your own modules that are guaranteed to maintain their relative location at runtime or when parsed by build systems calling the TS compilier.

Perhaps those clauses of the docs predate the addition of wildcards and need an update to clarify behaviour in the presence of wildcards. I've raised [an issue ticket (#2559)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/issues/2559) on the TS Website repo for discussion on this matter.

Comment: Dang, that works! Thank you so much for this answer, it's incredibly informative. I just assumed `*.yaml` was globbing onto the beginning of the file name, never considered it was matching the whole relative path.